# wicket-bootstrap breadcrumb in navbar

Tags: java, html, css, wicket

Is it possible to add breadcrumb to the navbar using [wicket-bootstrap](https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap)?

BasePage.java

```
public BasePage(final PageParameters params) {
    super(params);
    add(createNavbar("navbar"));
    add(new Footer("footer"));
    add(newBreadcrumb("breadcrumb"));
}

protected Navbar createNavbar(String markupId) {
    Navbar navbar = new Navbar(markupId);

    navbar.setPosition(Navbar.Position.TOP);
    navbar.setInverted(true);

    navbar.setBrandName(Model.of("Title"));
    navbar.add(newBreadcrumb("breadcrumb"));

    return navbar;
}

protected Component newBreadcrumb(String markupId) {
    Breadcrumb breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb(markupId);
    breadcrumb.setActive(new BreadCrumbPanel("breadcrumbid", breadcrumb) {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 165186734860620567L;

        @Override
        public IModel<String> getTitle() {
            return Model.of("Home");
        }
    });
    return breadcrumb;
}
```

BasePage.html

```
<div wicket:id="navbar" class="bs-docs-nav">
    <ul wicket:id="breadcrumb"></ul>
</div>
```

But i still get error, that i can't add anything into #navbar tag

```
For Navbar Components only raw markup is allow in between the tags but not other Wicket Component.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Navbar` component is working with `INavbarComponent` as children.

You should do something like:

```
Navbar navbar = new Navbar("id");
navbar.addComponents(new INavbarComponent() {
    @Override
    public Component create(String markupId) {
        return new NavbarButton(Page.class, Model.of("Link Name"));
    }

    @Override
    public Navbar.ComponentPosition getPosition() {
        return Navbar.ComponentPosition.LEFT;
    }
});
```

This is taken from `IssuesPage` in the samples module.

If this doesn't help then your last option is to put the breadcrumb solely in the markup. But I guess you need to control the `active` crumb, so this may not really help.

Bootstrap navbar is a complex component. They are going to simplify it in ver.4. Then I hope it will be simpler in Wicket-Bootstrap too.